# Windows attrib command line program doesn't remove readonly attribute?

Tags: windows, cmd

I use windows attrib command to remove directory readonly attribute and set it back like this:

```
attrib -r C:\build
attrib C:\build
    C:\build
attrib +r C:\build
attrib C:\build
R   C:\build
```

The question is why after removing readonly attribute from command line I still see it in directory properties dialog (right click in windows explorer and select properties).

Comment: attrib only modify files attributes, use /s /d if you want to process directory from the current path. look here http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Explorer checkbox just doesn't work the way you think it does.  It's UI is very confusing and has tripped up many users.

It is used to change the RO attribute of the *files* in the directory, it does **not** indicate the state of the directory itself.  You'll always see it in its "indeterminate" state at first.  Then you turn it on or off, keep clicking on it to see it cycle through the three different states.  Unchecked, checked (checkmark in the box) and indeterminate (rectangle in the box).  Then you click the Apply button and it will set the RO attributes on the **files** in the directory to match the checkbox state.

You cannot see the state of the RO attribute of the directory itself in Explorer.  By design, the attribute is only meaningful on files.

Answer (score 1):

The read-only attribute doesn't apply to folders. The check box in the Explorer properties dialog is only for changing the attribute of files in a folder. See the "More Information" section in [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549).

Comment: Good, but why I see attribute change in command line? Isn't it weird?

Comment: Because you can set/modify it, even though it's being disregarded. And yes, it *is* weird.