# Remove windows file readonly attribute in gulp file

Tags: gulp, readonly-attribute

How can we remove readonly attribute from all files under a folder in Windows?

**UPDATE**:
The question is more about how to remove readonly attribute using gulpfile

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows attrib command line program doesn't remove readonly attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650924/windows-attrib-command-line-program-doesnt-remove-readonly-attribute)

Comment: the linked question does not answer how to do it in gulp

Answer (score 7):

I figured out the answer:

To remove readonly attribute of all files under a directory recursively, we run the following command in windows Command line

```
attrib -r <dir-name>\*.* /s
```

Following gulp task removes readonly attribute of all files under

```
gulp.task('remove-readonly-attributes', function() {
    require("child_process").exec("attrib -r <dir-name>\*.* /s");
});
```

Comment: Always provide all callback when not returning a gulp stream: `function(done) { require("child_process").exec("command", done); }`

Comment: This seems to be the only solution that works for me on my Windows workstation

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this problem with gulp-chmod.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-chmod