# How can I provide write permission to index.html while injecting js and css in gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I use perforce for code checkin in our private server, so after production build (i.e., when index.html is read only) my gulp task fails with below error.

```
[INFO] [11:30:19] Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\MyProjectDir\index.html'
```

Once I checkout files or uncheck the read only property (using windows box) the gulp task finishes successfully. Is there a way to change it's permission through gulp task to avoid this manual intervention?

PS: I have used chmod(777)

Gulp file (end part where inject takes place)

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    minify = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    concatVendor = require('gulp-concat-vendor'),
    concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    clone = require('gulp-clone'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    del = require('del'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    chmod = require('gulp-chmod'),
    series = require('stream-series'),
    ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate'),
    rename = require("gulp-rename");
...
gulp.task('index', ['gulp-js-files', 'gulp-css-files'], function() {
    var target = gulp.src(mainIndexFile);
    return target.pipe(chmod(777)).pipe(inject(series(vendorCss, customCss, vendorJs), { ignorePath: ['MyProjectDir'], addRootSlash: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(mainDestination));
});
...
```

Running cmd in Administrator mode

[image]

Comment: How could you do `chmod(777)` on `Windows`?

Comment: @xAqweRx: It's a nodejs module and in docs it has no where mentioned that it cannot be used on windows, instead it says "can be used everywhere" https://www.npmjs.com/package/chmod

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood about `chmod`. Just a thought - have you tried start your `cmd` with `administrative` wrights?

Comment: @xAqweRx: Yes I start `cmd` with Administrator priviledge

Comment: Is the intent to change paths to JS files?

Comment: Refer this for solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483772/remove-windows-file-readonly-attribute-in-gulp-file. If this also is not working the your IDE or anti-virus could be blocking the files. Try closing the IDE and turning of the anti-virus for a while.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use [`gulp-exec`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec) to remove the read-only flag with `attrib -r`, then re-set it with `attrib +r` after injecting the data (if necesarry).

Following is an example:

```
gulp.task('remove-readonly-attributes', function() {
    require("child_process").exec("attrib -r <dir-name>\*.* /s");
});
```

Comment: Here you can find an example how to use what @Larkeith is say using gulp-exec: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483772/remove-windows-file-readonly-attribute-in-gulp-file.